# Xcode 8.3 can't connect Action which is defined in AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

Follow the Ry's Cocoa Book step by step, but everything is not as fine as demonstration in this book.

Im using latest Xcode8.3, and something called `storyboard` really makes me confusing,no xnib file exists...

[image]

what should I do

Comment: Try dragging the other way around (from the button on the storyboard to the action on the Inspector)

Comment: [You can't make connections between objects in different *scenes*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39141785/cant-connect-window-to-iboutlet-with-storyboard/39151476#39151476). Why is your `AppDelegate` handling this button anyway? It's sitting on the view controlled by `ViewController`, so this object should be the recipient of the button's action.

Answer (score 1):

Give the action the class name.

```
- (IBAction)sayHello: (NSButton *)sender {

}
```